# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry after building by Maven

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, javafx

I'm building an application using Maven. I have a database in local MySql, and everything seems to be alright when it is still in Eclipse environment. The connection between application and database is fully functional and there is nothing to worry about.
In Maven I set the goal "package" and nothing went wrong so far, but when the application wants to make a SELECT ALL query it encounters this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry
    at festival.AbstractFestivalDAOimpl.open(AbstractFestivalDAOimpl.java:28)
    at festival.FestivalsPane.FestivalDAOImpl.selectAllFestivals(FestivalDAOImpl.java:51)
    at festival.FestivalsPane.FestivalTable.getdata(FestivalTable.java:234)
    at festival.FestivalsPane.FestivalTable.<init>(FestivalTable.java:71)
    at festival.ArtFestivals$1.handle(ArtFestivals.java:148)
    at festival.ArtFestivals$1.handle(ArtFestivals.java:143)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 53 more
```

and here is my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Festival</groupId>
<artifactId>Festival</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.CR1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
  <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
  <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>io</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdftest</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.picasso</groupId>
  <artifactId>picasso</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.15.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.5</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
   <build>
     <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
     <resources>
       <resource>
         <directory>src</directory>
         <excludes>
           <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
         </excludes>
       </resource>
     </resources>
     <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.5.1</version>
       <configuration>
         <source>1.8</source>
         <target>1.8</target>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>festival.ArtFestivals</mainClass>    
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and lastly here is my code:

```
public class AbstractFestivalDAOimpl implements FestivalDAO{

    Session session;
    Transaction transaction;

    @Override
    public void open() {
        session = HibernateSessionFact.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        transaction= session.getTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void commit(){
         if(!transaction.wasCommitted()){

            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void close() {

        session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void addFestival(CinemaFestival cinemafestival) {
        session.save(cinemafestival);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteFestival(CinemaFestival cinemafestival) {
        session.delete(cinemafestival);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateFestival(CinemaFestival cinemafestival) {
        session.update(cinemafestival);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<CinemaFestival> selectAllFestivals(){
        String selall = "from festival.CinemaFestival";
        Query query = session.createQuery(selall);
        ObservableList<CinemaFestival> festlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        List<CinemaFestival> list = query.list();
        for(Object o : list){
            CinemaFestival c = (CinemaFestival) o;
            festlist.add(c);
        }
        close();
        return festlist;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<CinemaFestival> instantSearchFestivals(String key){
        String[] stringdata = {"fullname", "abbr" , "Country" , "City" ,
            "Website"};
        ObservableList<CinemaFestival> festlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (String s: stringdata){
            String selwhe = "from festival.CinemaFestival where " + s + " like :key";

            Query query = session.createQuery(selwhe);
            query.setParameter("key", "%" +key + "%");

            List<CinemaFestival> list = query.list();
            for(Object o : list){
            CinemaFestival c = (CinemaFestival) o;
            if (!festlist.contains(c)){
            festlist.add(c);
            }
        }
        }
        return festlist;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<CinemaFestival> advancedSearchFestivals(String s , HashMap <String,Object> map){

        ObservableList<CinemaFestival> resultlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Query query = session.createQuery(s);
        for (String key: map.keySet()){
            if (map.get(key) instanceof String){
            query.setParameter(key, "%" + map.get(key) + "%");
            }
            if (map.get(key) instanceof Boolean){
                query.setParameter(key, map.get(key));
            }
            if (map.get(key) instanceof Integer){
                query.setParameter(key, map.get(key));
            }
        }
            List list = query.list();
            for(Object o : list){
            CinemaFestival c = (CinemaFestival) o;
            if (!resultlist.contains(c)){
            resultlist.add(c);
            }
        }

        return resultlist;
    }

    @Override
    public void addClient(Client client) {
        session.save(client);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteClient(Client client) {
        session.delete(client);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateClient(Client client) {
        session.update(client);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Client> selectAllClients(){
        String selall = "from festival.Client";
        Query query = session.createQuery(selall);
        ObservableList<Client> clientlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        List<Client> list = query.list();
        for(Object o : list){
            Client c = (Client) o;
            clientlist.add(c);
        }
        close();
        return clientlist;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Client> instantSearchClients(String key){
        String[] stringdata = {"firstname", "surname" , "job1" , "job2" ,
            "mobile1" , "mobile2" , "home1" , "home2" , "work1" , "work2" , "other1" , "other2" };
        ObservableList<Client> clientlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (String s: stringdata){
            String selwhe = "from festival.Client where " + s + " like :key";

            Query query = session.createQuery(selwhe);
            query.setParameter("key", "%" +key + "%");

            List<Client> list = query.list();
            for(Object o : list){
            Client c = (Client) o;
            if (!clientlist.contains(c)){
            clientlist.add(c);
            }
        }
        }
        return clientlist;
    }

    @Override
    public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
        session.save(movie);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteMovie(Movie movie) {
        session.delete(movie);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMovie(Movie movie) {
        session.update(movie);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Movie> selectAllMovies(){
        String selall = "from festival.Movie";
        Query query = session.createQuery(selall);
        ObservableList<Movie> movielist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        List<Movie> list = query.list();
        for(Object o : list){
            Movie c = (Movie) o;
            movielist.add(c);
        }
        close();
        return movielist;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Movie> instantSearchMovies(String key){
        String[] stringdata = {"fullname", "language" , "section" , "genre"};
        ObservableList<Movie> movielist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (String s: stringdata){
            String selwhe = "from festival.Movie where " + s + " like :key";

            Query query = session.createQuery(selwhe);
            query.setParameter("key", "%" +key + "%");

            List<Movie> list = query.list();
            for(Object o : list){
            Movie c = (Movie) o;
            if (!movielist.contains(c)){
            movielist.add(c);
            }
        }
        }
        return movielist;
    }

    @Override
    public void addSubmit(Submitionrecord submit) {
        session.save(submit);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteSubmit(Submitionrecord submit) {
        session.delete(submit);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateSubmit(Submitionrecord submit) {
        session.update(submit);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Submitionrecord> selectAllSubmits(){
        String selall = "from festival.Submitionrecord";
        Query query = session.createQuery(selall);
        ObservableList<Submitionrecord> submitlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        List<Submitionrecord> list = query.list();
        for(Object o : list){
            Submitionrecord s = (Submitionrecord) o;
            submitlist.add(s);
        }
        close();
        return submitlist;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Submitionrecord> instantSearchSubmits(String key){
        String[] stringdata = {"fullname", "language" , "section" , "genre" , "duration"};
        ObservableList<Submitionrecord> submitlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (String s: stringdata){
            String selwhe = "from festival.Submitionrecord where " + s + " like :key";

            Query query = session.createQuery(selwhe);
            query.setParameter("key", "%" +key + "%");

            List<Submitionrecord> list = query.list();
            for(Object o : list){
                Submitionrecord s1 = (Submitionrecord) o;
            if (!submitlist.contains(s1)){
            submitlist.add(s1);
            }
        }
        }
        return submitlist;
    }
}
```

the line number 28 is:

```
session = HibernateSessionFact.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

Here is the mvn dependency:tree result

```
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:jar:4.3.1.CR1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- logkit:logkit:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- avalon-framework:avalon-framework:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- ant:ant:jar:1.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:jtidy:jar:r8-20060801:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.jdt.core:jar:3.9.1.v20130905-0837:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse:text:jar:3.3.0-v20070606-0010:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.core:commands:jar:3.3.0-I20070605-0010:compile (version selected from constraint [3.2.0,4.0.0))
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.9.0-v20130326-1255:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse:osgi:jar:3.10.0-v20140606-1445:runtime (version selected from constraint [3.7.0,4.0.0))
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.core:jobs:jar:3.6.0-v20140424-0053:runtime (version selected from constraint [3.2.0,4.0.0))
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.5.400-v20140428-1507:runtime (version selected from constraint [3.4.0,4.0.0))
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:jar:3.5.200-v20140224-1527:runtime (version selected from constraint [3.4.0,4.0.0))
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.core:contenttype:jar:3.4.200-v20140207-1251:runtime (version selected from constraint [3.3.0,4.0.0))
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.equinox:app:jar:1.3.200-v20130910-1609:runtime (version selected from constraint [1.0.0,2.0.0))
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.6.200-v20130402-1505:compile
[INFO] |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:barcodes:jar:7.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:font-asian:jar:7.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:forms:jar:7.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:hyph:jar:7.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:io:jar:7.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:kernel:jar:7.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:layout:jar:7.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:pdfa:jar:7.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:pdftest:jar:7.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:sign:jar:7.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.15.1:compile
[INFO] \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.5:compile
```

Anyone has any idea why am I getting this Exception?

Comment: Could you provide the output of the `mvn dependency:tree` command. This would help to determine if there are multiple versions of the same artifact being included, possibly transitively, in your classpath

Comment: How did you start the application? `mvn package` will _not_ bundle the dependencies in the jar, so you have to specify the classpath yourself when starting the application

Comment: I am new to Maven, so I used eclipse to generate the POM file for me. I just added a plugin to specify my main class and a dependency of  mysql connector and hibernate core. I set the goal to package in eclipse maven build wizard. It didn't ask for the classpath. @SilverNak

Comment: The first thing you need to learn in Maven is to follow conventions so the first one follow the [directory conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) furthermore remove configuration elements which change that...

Comment: I updated the question with the result of mvn dependency:tree @drembert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to answer my question. The problem was actually obvious, and was exactly because of lack of experience.
In the POM file I needed to add a classpath to the manifest and I did it like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>main.java.festival.ArtFestivals</mainClass>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer. but try this below steps to find out the issue.

1. Do Ctrl+Alt+T in your eclipse with the class name  **ServiceRegistry**. if you get the class then track it to the jar file it resides. Also make note of the version.
2. Get your dependency tree by using this command 
   **mvn dependency:tree**
3. Check whether the jar from step 1 with exact version is available in the dependency tree result.

Also as you have said you use the **package** as the maven goal. you might be missing the dependent hibernate-core jar in the classpath in your deployment target. 
Eg In case of a web application. the jar should be in **WEB-INF/lib** folder of your webapps folder in the server.

Comment: I found the ServiceRegistry using Ctrl+Alt+G and I found jar file and the version. It was exactly the same as the mvn dependency:tree. @Pravin K

Comment: I even changed the way I configure the session factory. but this time it throws the same exception with org.hibernate.cfg.configuartion which is in the same library 4.3.1.final @Pravin K