# NoClassDefFoundError while running project with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have simple project that uses Hibernate to connect to PostgreSql and when I try to run it, this error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry
    at Service.CatsService.<init>(CatsService.java:12)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 2 more
```

However, I have hibernate-core in my pom.xml, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cats</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've tried to change hibernate-core version, reboot IDE, change dependencies location in pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

**If you use IDEA, please click the button like below.**
[image]

**If you use Eclipse, please click the button like below.**
[image]

Comment: I tried, it didn't help

Comment: Does this answer of your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367304/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-service-serviceregistry-after-buil

Comment: No, that didn't work to